# Swift iOS backgroundTaskIdentifier or Background Fetch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Swift 2.0 background task (backgroundTaskIdentifier and Background Fetch)

Notice : I used two method background fetch and backgroundTaskIdentifier but cancel background process

> Hi , this sample code working in XCode debug monitor (Active & Background mode) , but after disconnected iPhone device and launch manually application -> press home and go to background mode -> after a while app closed (suspended).

there is anyway to prevent this or having a new idea to keep background process alive ?

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler(
    {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(20, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    })
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(20, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    return true
}


func update()
{
    print("Hi There")
}
```

Comment: These sorts of background tasks can only run for a maximum of 3 minutes before they will be terminated by iOS.

Comment: Hi - Paulw11 , can you help me about this problem ?

Comment: This is one of those problems for which there isn't really a solution on the device. The best solution is to have the server send a push notification when there is new data or you can use background fetch but the checking interval is quite long

Comment: Yes i know , but this interesting when device connected with xcode and monitoring log without problem and 100% working

Comment: When the device is connected to Xcode the background time limit is removed, although if you check the `UIApplication.backgroundTimeRemaining` property you will see that it decrements to 0 and then stays at that value. When the debugger isn't connected your background task will be terminated when this value reaches 0

Comment: i need like alarmmanager in android

Comment: iOS doesn't have any support for general purpose long-running background tasks

Comment: Paulw11 thanks a lot